# RegEx help in an awk script

Tags: awk

So I have a log file that contains entries like this:

```
[STAT] - December 11, 2017 13:16:05.360
.\something.cpp(99): [Text] Code::Open Port 1, baud 9600, parity 0, Stop bits 0, flow control 0

[STAT] - December 11, 2017 13:20:24.637
.\something\more\code.cpp(100): [log]
fooBarBaz[32] = 32, 1, 2, 7, 3, 1092, 5, 196875, 6, 270592, 20, 196870, 8, 289, 30, 196867, 11, 1156, 5, 196875, 28, 278784, 5, 196874, 32, 266496, 30,  6866, 36, 147712, 5, 196874,

[STAT] - December 11, 2017 13:20:40.939
.\something\more\code.cpp(100): [log]
fooBarBaz[8] = 8, 1, 2, 1, 31, 532992, 5, 196875,

[STAT] - December 11, 2017 13:18:16.214
.\something\more\code.cpp(100): [log]
fooBarBaz[12] = 12, 1, 2, 2, 17, 296960, 10, 196872, 51, 1792, 50, 196878,
```

On the command line, I can do this:

```
gawk -F', *' '/fooBarBaz\[[^0].*\]/ {for (f=5; f<=NF; f+=4) print $f | "sort -n" }' log
```

Which produces an output like this:

```
3
6
8
11
17
28
31
32
36
51
```

I'd like to have an awk script do the same thing, but my efforts so far haven't
worked.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gawk -f                                                                                                                                                             

BEGIN { print "lines"
        FS=", *";
        /fooBarBaz\[[^0].*\]/
}
{
                {for (f=5; f<=NF; f+=4) print $f} 
        }
```

I don't think my regular expression statement is in the right place, because
running gawk -f script.awk prints lines not relevant to my data.

What am I doing wrong?

tl;dr: On lines with fooBarBaz and not [0], I want to parse the digits starting at position 5 and then position 4 to the end of the line.

Comment: your regular expression should be before the second `{` and not in the BEGIN statement.

Comment: Moving it out of the begin statement still picks up the data in `\something.cpp`. `flow control 0` happens to be the 5th comma, but I don't care about that.

Comment: Your refactored script seems to have the expressions in different order and lack the pipe to sort. Why would you expect that to produce the same result? Is there a copy/paste error you can fix with an [edit] of your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimized GNU **`awk`** solution:

`parse_digits.awk` script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
    FS=", *";
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";
    print "lines";
}
/fooBarBaz\[[1-9]+[0-9]*\]/{
    for (i=5; i <= NF; i+=4) 
        if ($i != "") a[$i]
}
END{
    for (i in a) print i
}
```

---

Usage:

```
awk -f parse_digits.awk inputfile
```

The output:

```
lines
3
6
8
11
17
28
31
32
36
51
```

Comment: Nice! Can you explain what's happening in it?

Comment: @RegisteredUser, All needed digits are captured as array `a` indices (`a[$i]`). The crucial line is `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"` - it'll arrange an array indices in ascending order (so you don't need calling `| sort -n`)

Comment: `/fooBarBaz\[[^0]+\]/` couldn't match `[10]` for example, I think the OP just wants to avoid matching `[0]` which would be satisified by `/fooBarBaz\[[^0].*\]/`.

Comment: @EdMorton, the moment that should be additionally elaborated is whether it should match only digits except single `0` OR any char(s) except `0`.

Comment: The OP did say `lines with fooBarBaz and not [0]` so between that and her sample input where it's always numbers between `[...]` and the code she provided that tests for `fooBarBaz\[[^0].*\]` IMHO it's clear what she wants but she can chime in if she cares...

Comment: @EdMorton, I wander, how did you define **she**? )

Comment: There's no way to determine gender from a name like "Registered User" but I've got to use SOME pronoun and "she" is as good as "he" and better than "it" :-). We too often assume "he" by default.

Comment: No more than if she is a woman and I referred to her as "he" which I suspect happens WAY more often than the reverse! Gotta crush those stereotypes where you can :-).

Comment: @EdMorton, "crush stereotypes and make people think ..."

Comment: Exactly. Now if we can just stop people being interviewed on TV referring to white guys as "A man" and black guys a "A black man" we will have changed the world :-).